# Comparing cell with cell in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trigger in my database table on update and insert. I'm trying to compare old cell with new cell.

```
--Part of my table that is relevant
-------------------------------------------
ID
Changed_Date
Name_new
.
.
Name_old
```

The old and new data goes in the same row and different cells correctly from the trigger but I get redundant duplicates every time I load(update) the same customer base into my database.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE Name_New <> Name_Old
ORDER BY Changed_Date DESC
```

There is no need for the costumers who have the same new and old information to be loaded into the database. A little help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
I will try to illustrate by example to make it a bit more clear

```
ID | Changed_Date   | Name_New    | Name_Old
   |-----------------------------------------
    --Loading my Application the 7th november and fetcing data to insert again

  1| 2016-nov-7 etc | John Smith  | John Smith
    --Loading my Application 6th november and fetching data to insert into my Database

  1| 2016-nov-6 etc | John Smith  | Heather Smith
```

There is nothing new on the 7th november so I there is no need to have anything displayed. My SELECT above is suppose only show data on the 6th november since Heather changed name to John.

```
   ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_CreateRevision]
ON [dbo].[Main_Customers_Table] AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Customers (
        CustomerID,
        ChangedDate,
        Name_New,   
        Name_Old,       
    )
    SELECT  [Old].ID,
            GETDATE(),
            [New].Name,
            [Old].Name,     
    FROM inserted AS [New]
    CROSS JOIN
    deleted AS [Old]
END
```

Comment: What does the trigger do? Does it insert the data that you are selecting in another table? You would probably get redundant duplicates. The condition `WHERE Name_New <> Name_Old` will evaluate to true everytime.

Comment: You should compare with Inserted table. You will get new values in inserted table before it committed.

Comment: Do research on the `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables. Eg [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) is the first one when I use my search engine.. Maybe I'm not entirely clear on your actual problem.

Comment: @PrabodhMhalgi updated the with the trigger. TT ty for the link

Comment: @TT. im trying to compare the value of cell Name_new with Name_old, if they match then I do not want to display them in my gridview